# Novice WordPress Installation issues

Tags: installation

I am trying to install WordPress on [www.000webhost.com](http://www.000webhost.com/)

I have uploaded the most recent version of WordPress to the server and created a MySQL database. However, When I visit my site, I select the WordPress folder and it gives two error messages:

> Warning: require_once(/home/username/public_html/wordpress//wp-includes/class-wp-error.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/a5558093/public_html/wordpress/wp-load.php on line 48
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/username/public_html/wordpress//wp-includes/class-wp-error.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/username/public_html/wordpress/wp-load.php on line 48

What do these mean? How can I solve these issues?

Answer (score 2):

After reading [this](http://www.000webhost.com/forum/before-registration/13273-few-words-how-instal-wordpress-000webhost-com-servers.html), I realized that the problem was that I needed to take the contents out of the "wordpress" folder, paste them in parallel to the "wordpress" folder, and delete the "wordpress" folder. Everything works fine now. Thankyou all.

Answer (score 1):

I'll guess it has something to do with that extra `/` in the path `wordpress//wp-includes`, though I'm not sure why that's happening. Possibly an issue with how it's defining the `ABSPATH` setting in wp-load.php

Comment: It's not a good idea to disregard double slashes, but in practice in the middle of the path they are almost always harmless both on Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This happens in a branch of code that is triggered when config files is missing on load, but if you had no chance to go through installation dialog yet that would be accurate...

Can yo verify that file it references is present and its content is sane? Maybe your upload got broken or cut short.

Comment: That could be it. I am re-uploading it now.

Comment: I have tried several times to upload the zip file using the file manager that is default on 000webhost.  However the problem persists.